# lightning quick action not visible in salesforce classic

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

i have a lightning quick action in my page layout. But the quick action is not visible in Classic View.

however, according to the documentation, it should be visible.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview.htm&type=5

is there any step that i am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Lightning Quick Action/Lightning Component Actions is only available in Salesforce mobile app and Lightning Experience. The document you have share have the only describe Quick Action Not about Lightning Quick Action/Lightning Component Actions.

Use the following link for more details:-

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_component_actions.htm&type=5